# Is is legal to include a bot software into an installation by explaining to the user?

Tags: software

I made a bot program which only visits some websites automatically (not a virus, worm, trojan and etc) and I'm planning to install it as an additional program near main program.

I know it is illegal but if I wrote some information about this bot in the usage statement which people should accept that before installing the main program, would it be legal?

Comment: Which country's laws are you interested in?

Comment: @Mark mainly Iran :) and what about USA?

Comment: In Germany it would probably matter if you hid it deep in the EULA or if you included an additional checkbox (unchecked by default) with a descriptive label.

Comment: Why is it illegal? If it's illegal to run that bot, I find hard that under Iran legislation it is legal to make other people commit illegal things. With the aggravant that the user possibly doesn't fully understand it. Note that if the bot also had legit uses, it could be legal…